Centering text in python docx after creating a bookmark
I have two functions, one creates a paragraph with a bookmark in a document, and the other one puts text given a bookmark name.
def add_medidores_bookmarks(self, medidores_list):
        #esta funcion se aplica para crear marcadores de todos los medidores, a los que posteriormente se accederán para insertar tablas y gráficos
        for medidor in medidores_list:
            pt = self.doc.add_paragraph()
            bookmark_name = f'{medidor}_title'
            # get the paragraph element
            element = pt._p

            # add bookmark start before the first subelement
            start = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:bookmarkStart')
            start.set(docx.oxml.ns.qn('w:id'), '0')
            start.set(docx.oxml.ns.qn('w:name'), bookmark_name)
            element.insert(0,start)

            # add bookmark end after the last subelement
            end = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:bookmarkEnd')
            end.set(docx.oxml.ns.qn('w:id'), '0')
            end.set(docx.oxml.ns.qn('w:name'), bookmark_name)
            element.append(end)

            pb = self.doc.add_paragraph()
            pb.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER 
            bookmark_name = f'{medidor}_body'
            # get the paragraph element
            element = pb._p

            # add bookmark start before the first subelement
            start = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:bookmarkStart')
            start.set(docx.oxml.ns.qn('w:id'), '0')
            start.set(docx.oxml.ns.qn('w:name'), bookmark_name)
            element.insert(0,start)

            # add bookmark end after the last subelement
            end = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:bookmarkEnd')
            end.set(docx.oxml.ns.qn('w:id'), '0')
            end.set(docx.oxml.ns.qn('w:name'), bookmark_name)
            element.append(end)
            pb.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER # not working
        self._named_bookmarks = self._get_named_bookmarks()


I'm interested in centering the text of te second paragraph. Then this is the function that adds text given the bookmark:
def insert_text_after_bookmark(
        self,
        text: str,
        bookmark_name: str,
        font_name: str = "Arial",
        font_size: Length or None = Pt(12),
        style: set or None = None,
        text_color: tuple or None = None,
        throw_error: bool = False
        ) -> None:

        bookmark = self.get_bookmark_by_name(bookmark_name, throw_error = throw_error) # returns a xml element
        if bookmark is None:
            print("Advertencia: no existe una marca de posición con el nombre especificado.")

        else:
            paragraph = self.doc.add_paragraph()
            run = paragraph.add_run(text)

            if font_size is not None:
                run.font.size = font_size
            
            if font_name is not None:
                run.font.name = font_name
            
            if text_color is not None:
                run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(text_color[0],text_color[1],text_color[2])

            if style is not None:
                style = set([st.lower() for st in style])
                if style.intersection(self._allowed_bold_styles):
                    run.bold = True

                if style.intersection(self._allowed_italic_styles):
                    run.italic = True

                if style.intersection(self._allowed_underline_styles):
                    run.underline = True

            bookmark.addnext(run._element)

I'm trying to center the text in the second paragraph that the first function creates, in which I'm going to add text later.
